# Pointer version of itoa

Tags: c, beginner, pointers

> Rewrite appropiate programs from earlier chapters and exercises with pointers instead of array indexing. Good posibilities include `getline`(Chapter 1 and 4), `atoi`, `itoa`, and their variants(Chapters 2, 3, and 4), `reverse`(Chapter 3), and `strindex` and `getop`(Chapter 4)

Here is my solution:

```
static char *hidden(int n, char *s) {
    char *p;

    if(n / 10) {
        p = hidden(n / 10, s);
    }
    else {
        p = s;

    }
    *p++ = n % 10 + '0';
    *p = '\0';

    return p;
}

char *itoa(int n, char *s) {
    if(n < 0) {
        *s = '-';
        hidden(-n, s + 1);
    }
    else {
        hidden(n, s);
    }

    return s; /* pointer to first char of s*/
}
```

`itoa` is a wrapper for the function `hidden`. The function `hidden` returns a pointer to the next free slot in the array `s`. At the deepest level of recursion it returns a pointer to the first element (the else branch) of the array.

Comment: I think that this is the most relevant function that needs pr, the other ones are quite simple. If you want to see them: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwF4dzZ2k9NRVnl0ZUEtTE0yQUE&usp=sharing

Comment: Please give a better name (and some explanatory comments) to your `hidden` function. It's hard to tell what the function does.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use recursion for this. It is hard to read, inefficient and dangerous. I think the [classic K&R](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdlib.h/itoa) implementation of this algorithm is hard to beat in terms of efficiency. (But of course, K&R code is always an unreadable mess, filled with dangerous programming practice, so that snippet would need a code review of its own.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard version of itoa takes a parameter named base (which you have assumed is 10).

You probably don't need a second hidden function; this would do instead:

```
if (n < 0)
{
    *s++ = '-';
    n = -n;
}
// ... itoa implementation continues here ...
```

Recursing is clever; you could also probably do it with two loops instead (untested code ahead):

```
i = 1;
while ((i * 10) <= n)
    i *= 10;
for (; i != 0; i /= 10)
{
    int x = n / i;
    *p++ = (char)(x % 10 + '0');
    n -= (x * i);
}
assert(n == 0);
```

Comment: There is no standard version of itoa. As in: how it should behave isn't specified anywhere.